# Execute a command (to generate random strings) inside awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am using the below line of `AWK` code replace all occurrences of 7833 in my comma separated file with a random integer between 100 and 400.

```
awk -F \, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $NF == 7833 { $NF = int(rand() * 300 + 100) } 1' ./OldFile.txt > ./NewFile.txt
```

This works perfectly but now I want to replace 7833 with a random string from the below command.

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'A-Z0-9' | head -c 10
```

I tried using the below command but it is not working.

```
awk -F \, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $NF == 7833 { $NF = `cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'A-Z0-9' | head -c 10` } 1' ./OldFile.txt > ./NewFile.txt
```

Could you please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the AWK man page:

```
system(cmd)
executes cmd and returns its exit status
```

The GNU AWK manual also has a section that, in part, describes the system function and provides an example:

```
system("date | mail -s 'awk run done' root")
```

Now you should use something like this:

```
awk -F \, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $NF == 7833 { $NF = system("cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'A-Z0-9' | head -c 10") } 1' ./OldFile.txt > ./NewFile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately this doesn't work. I get error saying `tr: write error: Broken pipe`. Also, I tried a different command but since `system` returns the exit status it is replacing the number by 0 (status) and the random string in a new line. This is close but I think what I need is something which just executes the command and returns its output (not the exit status).

Comment: system() doesn't return stdout to awk, it only returns the exit code of the command you ran